# What do you call a human who can take energy from other living objects?

Tags: myth-identification, folklore

I'm not exactly sure what to think but after doing it so often I was just curious if there is a name? I've noticed that when I'm tired while say I'm at work I can place my palm to a tree and it begins to wake me up. The only way I can describe this feeling is like I've chug down an energy drink or something I can also do this with another human being. I sat down with a friend of mine and asked him to hold my hand he thought it was weird at first but when I held his hand I asked him if he felt anything and he described it it like a "pull" and when I used my other hand my left hand he said that the feeling was different like he was waking up.

Answer (score 1):

Only did a quick search but didn't find any mythological creatures with this attribute. Is there a mythological 'psychic vampire'?

However, did find a conversation about the ability, which may give you a direction to follow. Having no shared experience, I neither endorse nor oppose what is said in the linked thread:

[Absorbing Energy From Trees | Shaolin Wahnam Institute Virtual Kwoon and Discussion Forum](https://www.wongkiewkit.com/forum/forum/suggested-reading/articles-and-popular-topics/396-absorbing-energy-from-trees)

Snippet:

> This is not an approach I am familiar with, but overall I certainly do
>   not agree with such practices. A student recently asked me regarding
>   stories of Chi Kung practitioners killing vegetation with such
>   practices and I will give the same answer I gave him.
>
> Drawing energy from any other living creature for any reason other
>   than the immediate betterment of that living creature is not what I
>   would expect of any noble Chi Kung practitioner. In this case and from
>   what you have written, if he was knocked away by the energies he was
>   taking, then he should not have been taking them. Giving energies back
>   into the cosmos in whatever form is part and parcel of existance.
>   Deliberately taking something from another being without permission is
>   theft.
>
> I would also describe it as low to mid level Chi Kung, as the cosmos
>   supplies an endless source of pure, clean energy that is free to all -
>   why take from another?
>
> As I say, I am not familiar with this as a specific technique or
>   practice so if anyone would care to explain to me exactly why someone
>   would use such a practice I look forward to hearing their views.